# Push function is not working properly localStorage Javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am doing a time-to-click game as you can imagine  the fastest time would be the first place. I just want to have 3 scores. and have it on localstorage but every time I start a new game the actual score resets its value and it doesnt generate other scores. the 3 scores should have as value 0. I tried to push them as arrays but push function is not working well. at this point I am stuck. I dont know what to do. If u may help me, I would be really grateful, thanks!

```
let times = Array.from({
  length: 3
})


let interval2;

// Timer CountUp
const timerCountUp = () => {
  let times = 0;
  let current = times;

  interval2 = setInterval(() => {
    times = current++
    saveTimes(times)
    return times
  }, 1000);
}

// Saves the times to localStorage
const saveTimes = (times) => {
  localStorage.setItem('times', JSON.stringify(times))
}


// Read existing notes from localStorage
const getSavedNotes = () => {
  const timesJSON = localStorage.getItem('times')

  try {
    return timesJSON ? JSON.parse(timesJSON) : []
  } catch (e) {
    return []
  }
}

//Button which starts the countUp
start.addEventListener('click', () => {
  timerCountUp();
})

// Button which stops the countUp
document.querySelector('#start_button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('click');
  times.push(score = interval2)
  getSavedTimes()

  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    clearInterval(interval2);
  }
})
```

Comment: `times.push(score= times)` is invalid syntax.

Comment: I put interval2 which has the time value but It still not working

Comment: `times` seems to be a single numerical value and not an array, so why are you `.push()`ing anything to it?

Comment: Thats why I put the function getSavedTimes() to convert it into an array and push it after that

Comment: Check your console and post any errors.

Comment: I would do it but I do not have errors. :/ What would you do?

Comment: @Phix It **is** valid synax, provided that `score` is in-scope. Just run this in the browser console: `var x = []; var y = 123; var z = null; x.push( z = y ); console.log( z );`

Comment: @Dai I stand corrected. Just never seen it before.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#start_button')` should be `document.querySelector('#stop_button')`, no?

Comment: I haven't dissected this fully yet but when you define an array of length _n_ then use `push()`, the new entry will be at position _n_, not `0`. So `Array.from({ length: 3 }).push(123)` will result in `[undefined, undefined, undefined, 123]`. I feel this is counter to the logic you're after

Comment: @Phil Yes I know what you are saying. But let's use your example. I thought that using  push in some way I could manipulate the 3 arrays and replace them with the actual value which would be a new score. I am searching a way to declare that 3 arrays with a default value of 0 not to have problems with undefined

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
// Button which stops the countUp
document.querySelector('#start_button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
```

Probably should be this:

```
// Button which stops the countUp
document.querySelector('#stop_button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
```

...considering you're already attaching an event-handler to `start`'s `'click'` event in the previous statement, and no-one would use `#start_button` as the `id=""` of a *stop* button.